# Parsing the 'token' param from POST `/api/payment/39290329032?token=3924`

Tags: node.js, express

For every `POST /api/payment/554ca3f92e452b03009c6195?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJtYWlsX2lkIjoiNTU0Y2EzZjkyZTQ1MmIwMzAwOWM2MTk1IiwiaWF0IjoxNDMxMDg2MDczfQ.gt9qj2BZDiShB0lNgO65C_NbiBtfTt17TFcJ99mSPJg`

I would get an `undefined` token

```
app.post('/api/payment/:mail_id', function(req, res) {
console.log(req.params.token); //debug
...
};
// => undefined

app.post('/api/payment/:mail_id', function(req, res) {
console.log(req.param.token); //debug
...
};
// => undefined
```

The only thing that did work was:

```
app.post('/api/payment/:mail_id', function(req, res) {
console.log(req.param('token')); //debug
...
};
// => eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJtYWlsX2lkIjoiNTU0Y2EzZjkyZTQ1MmIwMzAwOWM2MTk1IiwiaWF0IjoxNDMxMDg2MDczfQ.gt9qj2BZDiShB0lNgO65C_NbiBtfTt17TFcJ99mSPJg
```

But `req.param()` was deprecated, and while I've looked around at the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html), I can't find a reference to resolve a `?token` for a `POST` request.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want [`req.query`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.query), which contains all of the query parameters: `req.query.token`

Comment: so `req.query` isn't just for `GET` requests?

Comment: Just about any HTTP request can have query parameters in the request url.